# Why does my non-normal sample pass the normality tests?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I am running non-normal samples against normality tests, expecting it to fail.  However, the p-value {normaltest: 2.64, shapiro: 6.23} is much higher than 0.05 so I cannnot reject the null hypotheses that this was drawn from a normal distribution.  Could someone please enlighten me?

```
import random
from scipy.stats import shapiro
from scipy import stats

x = list()

for y in range(1000):
     x.append(random.randrange(1,100))

print(stats.normaltest(x))
print(shapiro(x))
print(x)

NormaltestResult(statistic=500.02063130202464, pvalue=2.641797311523516e-109)
(0.9599024057388306, 6.233162463518298e-16)

[25, 94, 79, 12, 67, 27, 89, 94, 89, 34, 99, 58, 53, 29, 81, 94, 4, 52, 14, 19, 60, 26, 6, 85, 71, 57, 23, 13, 58, 75, 75, 10, 51, 12, 80, 3, 82, 64, 74, 57, 83, 15, 23, 45, 52, 51, 36, 61, 78, 50, 26, 72, 40, 19, 59, 90, 23, 71, 52, 25, 3, 16, 20, 62, 50, 56, 60, 73, 28, 96, 69, 80, 36, 11, 11, 7, 18, 1, 73, 17, 29, 57, 72, 87, 43, 18, 22, 54, 32, 35, 79, 27, 45, 81, 80, 79, 82, 49, 77, 73, 21, 17, 90, 96, 2, 72, 7, 43, 37, 72, 64, 53, 63, 5, 36, 74, 36, 59, 53, 55, 54, 15, 83, 65, 2, 64, 46, 51, 31, 1, 77, 28, 47, 75, 46, 56, 3, 16, 24, 27, 31, 66, 4, 61, 46, 2, 56, 59, 98, 86, 83, 86, 97, 59, 45, 80, 55, 23, 21, 61, 6, 20, 13, 54, 20, 58, 86, 38, 18, 47, 68, 52, 74, 19, 34, 56, 17, 91, 15, 54, 82, 95, 23, 54, 42, 81, 82, 6, 70, 1, 78, 49, 12, 25, 33, 38, 47, 41, 68, 75, 73, 76, 46, 7, 90, 89, 63, 43, 41, 46, 88, 14, 97, 37, 92, 76, 60, 7, 5, 56, 77, 98, 61, 60, 59, 64, 4, 76, 34, 84, 78, 39, 66, 24, 49, 60, 57, 13, 57, 18, 37, 52, 26, 36, 97, 47, 95, 26, 82, 82, 10, 76, 54, 67, 98, 22, 56, 20, 34, 76, 28, 50, 70, 87, 83, 13, 76, 87, 98, 29, 99, 29, 23, 74, 5, 54, 73, 31, 89, 10, 24, 15, 9, 34, 85, 23, 6, 25, 64, 94, 37, 30, 11, 9, 58, 43, 2, 1, 73, 49, 48, 41, 99, 30, 91, 17, 31, 58, 70, 46, 20, 33, 94, 35, 41, 19, 22, 2, 37, 8, 54, 41, 21, 16, 20, 65, 27, 68, 24, 19, 36, 63, 80, 12, 82, 74, 74, 46, 7, 36, 42, 72, 16, 26, 96, 48, 75, 86, 62, 20, 79, 66, 71, 43, 43, 96, 67, 97, 76, 40, 80, 97, 75, 2, 3, 97, 37, 78, 77, 25, 84, 82, 25, 87, 44, 80, 92, 95, 99, 48, 67, 12, 82, 3, 15, 40, 45, 94, 32, 87, 92, 24, 42, 73, 66, 20, 62, 9, 75, 51, 31, 3, 13, 76, 21, 32, 14, 58, 28, 14, 99, 14, 50, 45, 13, 83, 45, 59, 63, 39, 65, 78, 46, 96, 27, 16, 69, 42, 65, 68, 68, 90, 39, 50, 86, 7, 75, 93, 84, 23, 53, 31, 23, 63, 32, 60, 85, 67, 42, 5, 72, 44, 43, 98, 75, 55, 28, 99, 71, 72, 66, 46, 61, 52, 50, 16, 44, 63, 64, 32, 59, 73, 33, 36, 32, 45, 75, 44, 36, 74, 97, 2, 38, 30, 74, 12, 57, 11, 37, 83, 64, 3, 63, 3, 35, 61, 55, 59, 99, 51, 58, 63, 70, 84, 4, 18, 13, 51, 27, 75, 43, 63, 35, 76, 67, 32, 15, 54, 51, 31, 77, 97, 83, 50, 76, 87, 26, 55, 93, 31, 70, 5, 11, 54, 48, 55, 48, 76, 90, 75, 43, 34, 6, 22, 35, 29, 4, 47, 83, 44, 7, 2, 97, 74, 90, 91, 17, 12, 33, 52, 28, 95, 57, 22, 53, 83, 56, 71, 28, 76, 55, 12, 89, 27, 20, 20, 93, 43, 65, 34, 83, 92, 11, 22, 38, 90, 83, 77, 11, 5, 22, 73, 29, 67, 49, 16, 47, 60, 26, 20, 76, 57, 46, 70, 35, 9, 28, 33, 8, 33, 21, 65, 3, 67, 52, 45, 82, 32, 94, 89, 15, 27, 63, 53, 96, 4, 74, 29, 59, 67, 22, 24, 45, 63, 76, 66, 51, 28, 42, 83, 37, 56, 83, 14, 35, 99, 48, 93, 83, 76, 2, 20, 99, 41, 43, 61, 3, 13, 7, 74, 60, 17, 84, 16, 44, 76, 63, 85, 44, 27, 38, 29, 61, 34, 55, 91, 13, 31, 42, 35, 38, 6, 46, 31, 99, 85, 23, 67, 11, 4, 52, 57, 11, 9, 21, 64, 17, 46, 78, 83, 45, 68, 98, 88, 47, 1, 94, 24, 79, 47, 33, 7, 81, 12, 26, 99, 80, 78, 53, 88, 1, 49, 17, 91, 27, 44, 31, 20, 6, 46, 59, 40, 57, 80, 3, 72, 83, 81, 2, 27, 36, 94, 31, 30, 22, 26, 31, 14, 93, 11, 32, 14, 75, 17, 49, 54, 42, 56, 76, 42, 51, 69, 22, 86, 46, 97, 70, 24, 81, 3, 75, 81, 63, 48, 51, 72, 19, 16, 16, 1, 61, 95, 53, 36, 82, 93, 53, 65, 9, 40, 91, 41, 85, 65, 38, 59, 4, 92, 50, 51, 7, 87, 80, 45, 84, 57, 21, 44, 3, 52, 7, 53, 97, 46, 65, 37, 76, 7, 81, 49, 21, 25, 18, 84, 53, 84, 89, 5, 95, 69, 70, 56, 31, 69, 12, 72, 36, 12, 44, 94, 39, 97, 91, 92, 15, 17, 57, 17, 49, 47, 1, 8, 2, 93, 91, 29, 41, 12, 46, 75, 98, 14, 34, 6, 26, 6, 81, 75, 49, 61, 70, 83, 26, 83, 38, 40, 81, 27, 14, 40, 54, 35, 10, 22, 30, 38, 2, 95, 31, 32, 25, 88, 70, 33, 85, 52, 7, 47, 4, 87, 70, 90, 15, 53, 74, 45, 76, 50, 23, 54, 33, 90, 53, 70, 4, 6, 47, 77, 87, 60, 92, 94, 79, 36, 26, 20, 94, 59, 50, 72, 31, 25, 60, 24, 82, 93, 13, 57, 21, 72, 78, 27, 62, 67, 67, 62, 56, 40, 40, 49, 31, 52, 16, 67, 51, 87, 77, 1, 47, 49, 64, 48, 62, 90, 29, 68, 2, 39, 92, 89, 92, 34, 78, 48, 36, 32, 43, 26, 81, 22, 76, 95, 69, 79, 13, 77, 26, 70, 32, 21, 92, 97, 90, 98, 16, 81, 47, 83, 93, 50]
```

Comment: 2.631e-109 means 2.631/(10**109) so it is not actually greater than 0.05. It is a very small number, practically zero.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I needed to familiarize myself with scientific notation to understand this.